# Sorting words which are already put in a matrix in C programming language

Tags: c, sorting, matrix, character

I got a trouble about my program. I'm trying to creat random characters to make a word( do not consider the word sense). Actually several words. So I put them into  character matrix. But the problem is when I'm trying to sort them according to alphabet. I guess my trouble is only about sorting. I've tried to find it out for 2 hours. But nope :/. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    char text[100][100];
    int i, j, k, p = 0, m, isChanged=1, swap;

    srand((int)time(NULL)); 
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        k = (rand() %10) + 1;
        if (i<3 && k<5){
            k = (rand() %10) + 1;
        }       
        for(j=0; j<k; j++){
            text[i][j] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);   
        }
    }
    printf("The original list:\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(j=0; j<10; j++){
            printf("%c", text[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    i = 0; j = 0;
    while(isChanged = 1){
        isChanged = 0;
        while ( p = 0){
            if (text[i][j] > text[i+1][j]){
                for (m=0; m<10; m++){
                    swap = text[i][m];
                    text[i][m] = text[i+1][m];
                    text[i+1][m] = swap;
                    p = 1;

                }
            isChanged = 1;
            }
        j=j+1;
        }
    i = i + 1;
    j = 0;      
    }
    printf("The sorted list:\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        for(j=0; j<10; j++){
            printf("%c", text[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

At a wild guess, your sort loop never exits. That's because of this line

```
while(isChanged = 1)
```

which should, instead, be

```
while(isChanged == 1)
```

As written, your original line is equivalent to

```
loop:
    isChanged = 1;
    if (isChanged == 0)
        goto loop_end;

    // Body of loop
    goto loop:

loop_end:
```

You have the same problem with your inner loop

```
while ( p = 0)
```

Which will always evaluate to false and thus never enter the loop.

This problem is why veterans always code a comparison against a constant as

```
if (constant == variable)
```

or

```
while (constant == variable)
```

That way, the compiler will give you an error if you drop one of the `=` characters, converting it to an assignment. A constant is not a valid lvalue.

Further, as you are using `isChanged` and `p` as boolean variables, simply test them as follows

```
while(isChanged) {
    // ...

    while (!p) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You may have other problems in your sort, but until you fix these you're not going anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it :). I'm embarressed that I could't see the assignment mistake.

Comment: Don't be .. we all do it. It's one of the biggest traps in C (and C++)

Answer (score 1):

**Part i(Change char's sort in the word)**

First we have bubble sort:

```
void BubbleSort(char *a,int len){
int i,j,temp;
for(i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) 
{
    for(j = len - 1; j > i; j--)
    {
        if(a[j - 1] > a[j])
        {
            temp = a[j-1];
            a[j - 1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;    
        }
    }
}
}
```

And then call function in for loop:

```
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        BubbleSort(text[i],strlen(text[i]));
    }
```

BubbleSort to sort one word a time, we use for loop to loop n time for sort every words in the string.

**Part ii (Change word's sort in the string):**

```
    char swap[100];

for(k = 0 ; k < 10-1; k++){    
    for(p = 10-1; p > k; p--){
        if(text[p-1][0] > text[p][0]){
            *swap = *text[p-1];
            *text[p-1] = *text[p];
            *text[p] = *swap;
        }   
    }   
}
```

***Both part is using bubble sort algorithm***

[Bubble sort algorithm tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jdtq5uKz-w4)